# Are empirical models any better than theoretical models in economics?

Tags: macroeconomics

Why do we need sign restrictions in a VAR model? To solve puzzles in the data, it seems. And where do the signs come from? From theory, I guess. And about other restrictions we use in VAR models, where do they come from? Maybe intuition? But intuition is based on theory, yeah? So it seems data itself is not enough if we put restrictions on the VAR to identify shocks. Is this any better than using theory-based models like estimated DSGEs?

Comment: How do you define better? Also there is a lot of ranting in the question that makes it less clear what your question is asking about, perhaps consider trimming it down and focus on the question

Comment: It would help if you can be more clear about who the "they" in your post are, and include explicit citations for their opinions/views quoted herein.

Comment: ok...I will trim it down. Thanks!!

Comment: @Herr K THANKS! Critiques of estimated DSGEs are common. It is not difficult to find on google...:). I am just wondering, if not DSGE, then what? VAR? But is it any better since the VAR literature put a lot of restrictions on the VAR, and those restrictions come from theory embedded in DSGE.

Comment: @1muflon1 Better for identifying transmission mechanisms, I mean.

Comment: There is a huge literature on the relationship between structural VARs and DSGE models. I don't think this is something that can be given in a simple answer here.

Comment: @Michael Greinecker I think so. So, as a researcher, you choose where to belong, I guess. GLENN D. RUDEBUSCH and others criticize VARs and say they do not make sense. Others criticize DSGEs and say they do not make sense. So then what to use to study dynamical relationships and transmission mechanisms of some shock or policy? It boils down to which one you prefer, I guess. But my problem is some authors try to validate DSGE with VAR, but the VAR they use contains restrictions based on DSGE and common theory-based conventional wisdom.

Comment: @EmmanuelAmeyaw Specifics matter here a lot. If restrictions from a DSGE make an SVAR overidentified, one can use the data to test the restrictions. That there is a complicated debate does not mean that it all just a matter of preference. But it is unlikely that an answer can resolve the debate.

Comment: @Michael Greinecker. Thanks, Micheal. If I may ask, what do you mean by If restrictions from a DSGE make an SVAR overidentified, one can use the data to test the restrictions. Do you mean testing restrictions in an overidentified SVAR model when those restrictions come from a DSGE model? But that does not necessarily mean results from the SVAR, like IRFs, are correct, yeah? For example, the same SVAR model with the same restrictions for different sample periods can produce different IRFs.

Comment: Yes, pretty much. But there is no reason to believe any method gives you magically correct results. There is a reason why there is a debate.

Comment: @Michael Greinecker. It seems like it. Econometricians put restrictions to confirm their prior beliefs (their bias..:)). Theorists make assumptions to confirm their bias too. The true mechanism of how shocks propagate, no one knows...:).

Comment: That is your spin, not mine.

Comment: @Michael Greinecker. lol. So what's your spin? Or you don't have one? :). What is your view on the debate?...if I may ask?